# how to solve mod_wsgi python conflict error

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, server, apache2, mod-wsgi

Hi all i am using Apache mod_wsgi to deploy a python application but i am getting internal server error as:

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:01.285539 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25751:tid 140495002072960] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:02.395406 2017] [so:warn] [pid 26122:tid 140693819524992] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:02.396961 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26123:tid 140693819524992] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:02.396983 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26123:tid 140693819524992] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:02.397621 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 26123:tid 140693819524992] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:02.397650 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26123:tid 140693819524992] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707573 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008] mod_wsgi (pid=26126): Target WSGI script '/home/rajesh/mymapproxy/config.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707618 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008] mod_wsgi (pid=26126): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/rajesh/mymapproxy/config.py'.

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707636 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707655 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008]   File "/home/rajesh/mymapproxy/config.py", line 9, in

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707703 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008]     from mapproxy.wsgiapp import make_wsgi_app

[Fri Nov 17 17:26:28.707747 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 26126:tid 140693723956992] [client ::1:58008] ImportError: No module named mapproxy.wsgiapp

How can i fix this issue

Here is my apache configration: /etc/apche2/site-enabled/000-default.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /mapproxy /home/rajesh/workspace/mymapproxy/config.py
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    <Directory "/home/rajesh/workspace/mymapproxy/">
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
           Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

This is my /home/rajesh/workspace/mymapproxy/config.py

`from mapproxy.wsgiapp import make_wsgi_app
application = make_wsgi_app(r'/etc/mapproxy.yaml')`

Comment: The "module wsgi_module is already loaded" message is because your Apache configuration has a ``LoadModule wsgi_module`` line appearing twice somehow. The rest is likely because you haven't told mod_wsgi where your applicaition code is. It is not enough to just add ``WSGIScriptAlias`` if there are other files which are part of your application. Show your mod_wsgi configuration for your WSGI application.

Comment: Hi @GrahamDumpleton  i have redited my question and have given the apache configration. I think while instalation of mod-wsig its taking python version 2.7.11 but while runtime its taking 2.7.12, because of that may be its giving error. If its so please suggest any solution to get rid of this. Should i recompile mod-wsig with python 2.7.11. i dont know from where by default this python version of my ubuntu os is taking.

Comment: The version mismatch has got nothing to do with it. That is explained in documentation. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch

Comment: You are not setting the Python module search path so Python doesn't know where your code is. Read about using virtual environments, daemon mode and the Python module search path in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html You really should use a Python virtual environment for the packages you require and not install them into system Python directories.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton. Fixed this issue by creating virtual environment for python and using WSGIPythonHome tag in my default.conf file . I have placed it out of <VirtualHost> tag. It works like charm....thank you so much.